CORS Headers for Digital Ocean Functions
I see no way to set CORS headers for digital ocean functions, other than in my function responses. I'm calling a function from a different website via the REST API (POST request) using Basic Authorization, but setting headers in my function responses doesn't work. Preflight requests are all failing.
GET requests are working fine.
My response looks like this:
return {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
       "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Content-Type, Authorization",
       "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true,
       "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET",
       "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    },
    body: "Completed"
};


im also doing the same and suport told me to add on the shettings of the app platform but the thing is there i just get this error
"error": "Incomplete web function path. The path must contain /$namespace/$package/$function, $package can be 'default'."
like if is doent find the route of the function, but when i remove the cors settings it works normal the route

Strange! What setting did they ask you to change @DiegoRivera?

I have a feeling that preflight requests won't work due to the fact that the function requires authentication.

I don't think this is possible currently with Digital Ocean.
My plan for a workaround is to create a function on the web app which acts as a proxy for the standalone function. That way I won't get CORS problems as the function the browser is calling is part of the app and on the same domain.
The backend is not restricted by CORS as CORS is only for browsers, so it should be able to call my async standalone function without difficulty, and then report back to the static website.
It's a bit of a bodge but I don't see any other way forward. Once custom domains become a feature of standalone functions, things should be easier as then both the app and the function can be integrated into the same domain.
